# HMAC output in PHP not matching with one in Java

Tags: java, php, hmac

I'm trying to set up an API Connection which requires HMAC and encryption.
The documentation and sample output/code given to me is in Java but my website is in PHP. I'm on PHP 7.

What should I do so that my PHP output matches with that in Java sample output given in the API documentation?

I have tried to base64, utf8 and utf16 encoding on my PHP hmac output but still, the value is not matching.

**PHP code:**

```
$sb = '4a275929e0eba4445bc7f9a80c6361a2351119a27b51eebb2c259f68f72efd5f';
$keyToEncode = 'c0814229c201ab1022070741d15eda7af2189db64a2c88699c6481dbb83521afd8640d9af6d984602037d2e4f90c4f9a12915899290d944f385192b658829ec1;
$sb3 = hash_hmac('sha256',$sb, $keyToEncode);
```

**Java code**:

```
HMAC_SHA256(sb.toString(), keyToEncode);
```

**Output in PHP:**

```
2bea1f99897a8fd2e836e9d8f7820a28c03b76bf37daf04527f6f5d279c97fd7
```

**Expected output in Java:**

```
gWzlCNzu7fNN4z/uwvrgk574dTJqLQ8+25UMXCh+4tU=
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete source code of your java code, which can be compiled and tested, which generates/outputs the hash with the input you have.

Comment: Strings sb and keyToEncode is coming after series of steps and hashing. The outputs of which are matching in both php and java. That is why I did't mention those steps and directly gave the constants. In Java, I don't have a detailed code and this was shared in API documentation by a client with sample code snippet and expected output

Answer (score 0):

The following PHP-code reproduces the result from the Java-code:

```
<?php
$sb = 'c0814229c201ab1022070741d15eda7af2189db64a2c88699c6481dbb83521afd8640d9af6d984602037d2e4f90c4f9a12915899290d944f385192b658829ec1';
$keyToEncode = '4a275929e0eba4445bc7f9a80c6361a2351119a27b51eebb2c259f68f72efd5f';
$sb3 = hash_hmac('sha256',$sb, $keyToEncode); // HMAC-value as lowercase hexadecimal string
$sb4 = hex2bin($sb3);                         // HMAC-value as binary data  
$sb5 = base64_encode($sb4);                   // Base64-encoded HMAC-value 
print "HMAC-value (hexadecimal string): ".$sb3."\n"."HMAC-value (Base64-encoded): ".$sb5;
```

with the following output:

```
HMAC-value (hexadecimal string): 816ce508dceeedf34de33feec2fae0939ef875326a2d0f3edb950c5c287ee2d5
HMAC-value (Base64-encoded): gWzlCNzu7fNN4z/uwvrgk574dTJqLQ8+25UMXCh+4tU=
```

Here `$sb5` is the Base64-encoded HMAC-value which correponds to the Java-code result.

There are two flaws in your code:

1. The values for `$sb` and `$keyToEncode` were confused.
2. The PHP-method `hash_mac` has a fourth parameter `$raw_output` which is by default `FALSE`. When set to `FALSE` the result is returned as *lowercase hexadecimal string* otherwise as *binary data* (http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php). Since your PHP-code uses the default value of `$raw_output` (i.e. `FALSE`), the HMAC is returned as a hexadecimal string and must first be converted to binary data before it can be Base64-encoded. For the conversion the PHP-method `hex2bin` has to be used.

Btw, you can also use the `$raw_output = TRUE` variant. Then, no conversion with `hex2bin` is necessary. However, if you want to display the HMAC as hexadecimal string the PHP-method `bin2hex` has to be used:

```
<?php
$sb = 'c0814229c201ab1022070741d15eda7af2189db64a2c88699c6481dbb83521afd8640d9af6d984602037d2e4f90c4f9a12915899290d944f385192b658829ec1';
$keyToEncode = '4a275929e0eba4445bc7f9a80c6361a2351119a27b51eebb2c259f68f72efd5f';
$sb3 = hash_hmac('sha256',$sb, $keyToEncode, TRUE); // HMAC-value as binary data
$sb4 = base64_encode($sb3);                         // Base64-encoded HMAC-value
print "HMAC-value (hexadecimal string): ".bin2hex($sb3)."\n"."HMAC-value (Base64-encoded): ".$sb4;
```

with the same output as above.

Here `$sb4` is the Base64-encoded HMAC-value which correponds to the Java-code result.

Comment: Thank You. This worked.. Really appreciate in you putting in time and helping me out on this.